# Using range() within a function in Python

Tags: python, list, range

I am creating a function that should return a list of every third number between **start** and 100 (inclusive). For example, every_three_nums(91) should return the list [91, 94, 97, 100].
Initially, I tried the following:

```
def every_three_nums(start):
  list = []
  a = 0
  if start > 100:
    return list
  else:
    a = range(start, 101, 3)
    print(list(a))    

print(every_three_nums(91))
```

And I get TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

The same happens if I use

```
print(list(range(91, 101, 3)))
```

within the function. Despite this working outside the function.

I don't quite understand the rationale.
Could you help me with this?

Eventually, I solved with:

```
def every_three_nums(start):
  list = []
  a = 0
  if start > 100:
    return list
  else:
    for i in range(start, 101, 3):
      list.append(i)
    return list

print(every_three_nums(91))
```

Comment: In the first code, you declare list as a variable in the first code and then you call the list after some time.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the `list` function to a list instance inside the function with `list = []`. So when you call `list(a)`, you are treating a list *object* as a function. Rename that variable and it should work.